# Oracle SQL - Update procedure only non null values

Tags: sql, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have a simple update procedure. So, i wish to update **only** fields they are not **null values**. How can i do it?

```
  PROCEDURE UpdateCustomerInfo(
      CustomerID                 IN NUMBER,
      CustomerType                 IN VARCHAR2,
      CustomerName        IN VARCHAR2,
      CustomerGender          IN VARCHAR2,
      CustomerBirthday        IN DATE)
  AS
  BEGIN
    UPDATE CUSTOMER_INFO
    SET CUSTOMER_TYPE =CustomerType,
     CUSTOMER_NAME =CustomerName,
     CUSTOMER_GENDER =CustomerGender,
     CUSTOMER_BIRTHDAY =CustomerBirthday
    WHERE CUSTOMER_ID = CustomerID;
    COMMIT;

  END CUSTOMER_INFO
```

Anyone can help me?

Thanks

Comment: Do you want to avoid doing an update on the field?  Or do you want to avoid changing the value?  So if `CUSTOMER_BIRTHDAY` in the table is NULL and a `CustomerBirthday` of January 12, 1986 is passed in, you don't want to update the table?  That seems odd.  Perhaps you mean that you only want to change the data if the parameter values passed in to your procedure call are non-NULL?  I'm also confused as to why your `CustomerBirthday` is a `TIMESTAMP` rather than a `DATE`-- it seems unlikely that you're really asking a customer to provide their birth date to the millisecond.

Comment: Hello,

This SP is a simple example and yes, the timestamp is wrong :)
If the variables CustomerGender, CustomerBirthday or any one of them comes to null, I do not want to update, do not want these values appear to null. 
Do you understand?

Comment: Do you want to avoid doing the update?  Or do you want to avoid changing the value in the column?  My guess is that you merely want to avoid changing the value in the column.  But you may be trying to avoid updating the column (even to the same value) to avoid the cost of writing the redo or to avoid making changes that would need to get replicated somewhere.

Comment: I want to avoid changing the value in the column. But do not know how to do.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
UPDATE CUSTOMER_INFO
   SET CUSTOMER_TYPE     = NVL(CustomerType, CUSTOMER_TYPE),
       CUSTOMER_NAME     = NVL(CustomerName, CUSTOMER_NAME),
       CUSTOMER_GENDER   = NVL(CustomerGender, CUSTOMER_GENDER),
       CUSTOMER_BIRTHDAY = NVL(CustomerBirthday, CUSTOMER_BIRTHDAY)
 WHERE CUSTOMER_ID = CustomerID;
```

should do it.  The `NVL` function will return the second parameter if the first parameter is `NULL`.  So if the `CustomerType` parameter is `NULL`, the `CUSTOMER_TYPE` column will be updated to have the value that it already has.  You're still doing the update (generating redo for example) but you're not changing the data.